# Не работает клиент сокет Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, сокет, android-threads

Написал простой сервер с помощью сокетов. Его цель принимать данные от пользователя и отправлять их обратно
Клиент я написал в Android Studio, прием-передача (общение с сервером) вынесены в отдельные потоки Thread. По отдельности и отправка и прием сообщений работают, но когда хочу и слушать сервер (в бесконечном цикле) и отправлять ему данные - приложение вылетает.
Вот код клиента (без импортов):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Handler h;
public String message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    el = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    h = new Handler(); //Handler нужен для вывода ответа сервера на экран
    t.start(); //Запуск потока прослушивания ответа
}
```

По нажатию на кнопку вызывается этот метод, который запускает поток send в котором и должна происходить отправка сообщения на сервер:

```
public void sendmsg (View v) {
    send.start();
}
```

Здесь выполняется поток в котором прослушивается ответ сервера, он запускается сразу при запуске приложения

```
 Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("IP ADRESS", 8000);
               while(true) {
                   InputStreamReader listen = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
                   BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(listen);
                   final String message = buff.readLine();
```

После получения сообщения от сервера я присваиваю его в переменную и с помощью Handler пытаюсь вывести на экран

```
                   h.post(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   });
               }
                     }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Поток ниже должен становится активным во время вызова метода sendmsg, он отвечает за отправку сообщения серверу, сразу после отправки он должен становится неактивным

```
Thread send = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        try {
            Socket ssend = new Socket("IP ADRESS", 8000);

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(ssend.getOutputStream());
            writer.write("Сообщение серверу");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
}
```

По техническому заданию сначала сервер должен принять сообщение "Сообщение клиенту", после чего отправить его обратно, клиент это сообщение должен принять и вывести на экран через Toast.makeText, к серверу я подключаюсь но после отправки сообщения ничего дальше не происходит. Я думаю, может быть проблема в том что я в разных потоках обьявляю переменную сокета с одним и тем же адресом, но как исправить эту проблему я не понимаю. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: сервер то Ваше сообщение ловит?

Comment: Да, проблема была в том что для отправки и для приема нужно использовать разные порты